completeness of pseudometric space: details on the diagonalish argument
I was reading the Silverman translation of Kolmogorov and Fomin, in particular $\S7.4$ on the completion of a metric space. There is an example/remark on page 65 where it is claimed that the construction given can be used to construct $\mathbf R$ as the completion of $\mathbf Q$. However, this is not possible as given in the text, as their proof that a metric space completion always exists relies on the completeness of $\mathbf R$ (see page 63).
In the interest of avoiding circular reasoning, I set out to prove that $\mathbf R$ exists (as the completion of $\mathbf Q$).
It is clear to me that if a metric space completion exists, then it is unique up to isometry. (I've heard "unique up to unique isometry" before, but I don't know how to prove that, and I don't think it's going to enlighten me any further than "unique up to isometry" will. Maybe I'll concern myself with this later.) I need some help with showing existence, though.
I'm interested in doing this via the Cauchy sequence of Cauchy sequences construction, and I would like to form the quotient space as late as possible, i.e. I want to show that the pseudometric space of Cauchy sequences of rationals is complete first (rather than resort to the method of picking really nice representatives (i.e. rapidly converging Cauchy sequences) from the quotient space).
So, jumping to the part where I show the pseudometric space is complete, suppose $\Xi = (\xi_n)_n$ (where $\xi_n = (x_{(m, n)})_m$ and $x_{(m, n)}\in\mathbf Q$) is a Cauchy sequence of Cauchy sequences of rationals.
Then since $\Xi$ is Cauchy, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbf Q^+$ there is some $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for all $n, n'\ge N_\varepsilon$ there exists an $M_{n, n'}\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for any $m\ge M_{n,n'}$,
$$d_{\mathbf Q}(x_{(m,n)}, x_{(m, n')}) < \varepsilon.$$
Further, since each $\xi_n$ is Cauchy, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbf Q^+$ and $n\in\mathbf Z^+$ there is some $M_{n, \varepsilon}\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for any $m, m'\ge M_{n, \varepsilon}$,
$$d_{\mathbf Q}(x_{(m, n)}, x_{(m', n)}) < \varepsilon.$$
I need to show that there exists some $\xi_\infty = (x_{(f(n), n)})$ such that $\xi_\infty$ is Cauchy and $\xi_n\to\xi_\infty$.

$\xi_\infty$ is Cauchy means that for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbf Q^+$ there is some $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for $n, n'\ge N_\varepsilon$,
$$d_{\mathbf Q}(x_{(f(n), n)}, x_{(f(n'), n')}) < \varepsilon.$$

$\xi_n\to\xi_\infty$ means that for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbf Q^+$ there exists an $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for any $n\ge N_\varepsilon$, there is an $M_n\in\mathbf Z^+$ such that for any $m\ge M_n$,
$$d_{\mathbf Q}(x_{(m, n)}, x_{(f(n), n)}) < \varepsilon.$$


I'm having trouble finding a suitable $f(n)$.
